# In Rails, how do I delete all the objects in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, destroy

I am using Rails 5 and I want to delete an array of objects. In a previous thread, I read "destroy_all" was the truth and the light. I had two arrays of objects, which I subtract to get a third array

```
  unused_currencies = all_currencies - currencies_from_feed
  unused_currencies.destroy_all
```

but when using `destroy_all` I got this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `destroy_all' for #<Array:0x007feea8878770>
```

Comment: what defines `currencies_from_feed` assuming the `all_currencies` is literally `Currency.all` there is probably a clean scope that can be written to handle the collection of "unused_currencies" and then it is simple `Currency.unused_currencies.destroy_all` but without additional information it will be hard to help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code will make a single SQL query:

```
unused_currencies = all_currencies - currencies_from_feed
CurrencyModel.delete(unused_currencies)
```

where `CurrencyModel` is the model of your currencies.

You might want to use `destroy` if you need to run callbacks on the models:

```
unused_currencies = all_currencies - currencies_from_feed
CurrencyModel.destroy(unused_currencies.map(&:id))
```

This code will make a number of queries proportional to the number of unused currencies

Answer (score 0):

Destroy_all is for active-record type things.

What exactly are you trying to do? if you just want to get rid of the array, you can override it with

`unused_currencies = []`

If you're trying to destroy a bunch of active record objects in the array you're going to have to iterate over it and delete each object individually.

Answer (score 0):

`destroy_all` works for the `ActiveRecord::Relation`

If you want to clear the array, you can do: `unused_currencies = []`

If you want to delete each item in the in the array: 
`unused_currencies.each(&:destroy)`. This will generate a delete query per item.

To delete all the objects at once (assuming they all belong to the same model. This will blow up in your face if they don't!)

```
unused_currencies.first.class.destroy_all(unused_currencies.map(&:id))
```

Comment: Excuse me, I dont' want to clear the array, I want to delete all the objects in the array from the database.

Comment: @Dave Then use the second one

Comment: How many SQL statements will that create?  Is it possible to delete everything in just one SQL statement?

Comment: @Dave Yes, if you map all the ID's together but the items in array MUST be from the same model

Answer (score 0):

If you use `map`, you load in memory all data. I think you can just do:

```
all_currencies.where.not(id: currencies_from_feed.select(:id)).destroy_all
```

if `all_currencies` and `currencies_from_feed` are *ActiveRecord::Relation*, this will generate **only one request sql**.